# How to copy C++ dependencies into C# Project output?

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI project that has a dependency on a .dll file. I've set up a post build step to copy the .dll to $(OutDir), which works great when building the project.

Now, I have a C# project that references the C++/CLI project, but the .dll isn't copied to the C# $(OutDir).

There must be a way to just reference a C++ project without having to explicitly know about it's dependencies, right? It feels really icky to have to have my C# project directly reference into my C++/CLI project's dll folder. On top of that, it seems very error prone. I have two C# .exe projects that are referencing the C++/CLI project, so I (or a team member) have to remember to update the references to both C# projects if we end up with a new .dll reference in the C++ project...

Maybe some way during the C++/CLI project build to copy to the "parent" or "master" project output directory? I'm a C++ n00b and only somewhat familiar with the msbuild process, so any thoughts or solutions are welcome!

Comment: The C# and C++ build system use different conventions.  That does get you to fret about copying files where they should go but taming it has a *very* simple solution.  Change the setting.

Comment: Thanks as always Hans for the C++/CLI feedback! I'm a bit confused by which setting I would change though. I assume you mean change the C++ $(OutDir) to point to the C# project? I don't think that will work since I have two C# projects that reference the C++ project (which folder do I copy to?). Or is there perhaps a setting in the C# project I can change?

Comment: The problem which I'm really trying to solve is that I'd like to be able to create a new C# project, reference the C++/CLI project, build, and have it work. Since this is the first time I've encountered this issue, I'm trying to find a maintainable solution that I can use for this problem and all similar ones going forward. The worst case scenario that I'm trying to prevent is in the future when I'm gone, someone needs to add a reference to this C++ project, everything builds fine, then it blows up at runtime and they are left spending an entire day just trying to get it to work...

Comment: This is going a bit far afield (but you might like to do this in general): Publish the C++/CLI project to a [private NuGet repository](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) so projects that use it can reference it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Tom! We're going to go this route. Could you add this as an answer?